# Can I use svg images in QStyleSheet - pyside

Tags: svg, stylesheet, pyside, qtreeview

well I'm trying to use svgs for the QTreeView widget. I'm doing this with a simple stylesheet and was wondering if it is supported after i found nothing on the internet.

```
QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:!has-siblings,
QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:has-siblings  {
border-image: none;
image: url(C:/..../folder.svg);
width: 19px;
height: 16px;
margin: 2px 0px 2px 4px;
}
```

Problem is the svg is not showing.


Edit: 
Heres the svg: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9JmnAJW15XqcTc0TS1HNk80N0E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, svg images are supported. Are you absolutely certain that the url is valid? Try the same path with a jpg. Also: what specific version of Qt and PySide are you using?

Comment: Yes the Path is valid.
The PySide.__version__ says: 1.1.2.
The QtCore.__version__ is: 4.8.2

Comment: Well, i updated to the pyside version 1.2.4 and qtcore is now 4.8.7.
Still giving me a blank icon.

Comment: I tested with your svg image and was able to get it to work on Linux. Did you check that the same code works with a jpg image?

Comment: Yes, I also have a folder.png in this directory. The png works like a charm but the folder.svg is not showing.
I'm on windows 7...

Comment: If you do a websearch on `qt svg plugin windows` you will get quite a lot of hits on this issue. The problem seems to be that the plugins path is not configured properly, and so the svg plugin is not found.

Comment: In my case, trying to create a `QPixmap` from an `svg` file in pyside 1.2.4, the problem was solved by adding an import statement (without even using the imports), based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13531623): `from PySide import QtSvg, QtXml`